# generate argument-types in function typecast from variadic argument-types

Tags: c++

I want to call an arbitrary function in memory of which I have the memory pointer. Instead of creating a function template for each different function, I'd like to have a generic caller, that I can use on the fly.

Looking for something like that pseudo-code:

```
    template <typename R = uint64_t, uint64_t FunPtr, typename ...Args>
    R generic_call(Args... args)
    {
        using func = R(*)(TYPES_OF_ARGS...);
        return func(FunPtr)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
```

Is it possible to unfold the types within that typecast?

Answer (score 0):

solved it, i was just brainafk.

```
template <typename R, typename ...Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<R>>>
R generic_call(auto FunPtr, Args... args)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<__fastcall R(*)(Args...)>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(FunPtr))(args...);
}

template <typename R, typename ...Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<R>>>
void generic_call(auto FunPtr, Args... args)
{
    reinterpret_cast<void __fastcall (*)(Args...)>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(FunPtr))(args...);
}

int main()
{
    generic_call<int, some_func_ptr>(34);
    return 0;
}
```